# How is nth_element Implemented?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, selection, nth-element

There are a lot of claims on StackOverflow and elsewhere that `nth_element` is *O(n)* and that it is typically implemented with Introselect: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

I want to know how this can be achieved. I looked at [Wikipedia's explanation of Introselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) and that just left me more confused. How can an algorithm switch between QSort and Median-of-Medians?

I found the Introsort paper here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.5196&rep=rep1&type=pdf But that says:

> In this paper, we concentrate on the sorting problem and return to the selection problem only briefly in a later section.

I've tried to read through the STL itself to understand how `nth_element` is implemented, but that gets hairy real fast.

Could someone show me pseudo-code for how Introselect is implemented? Or even better, actual C++ code other than the STL of course :)

Comment: Did you notice that the algorithm should only be `O(n)` in the average case according to cppreference. It makes no statement about the worst case. This means quickselect would be viable as it has `O(n)` on average.

Comment: @Nobody cppreference also states that something other than Introselect may be used which may not be worst case *O(n)*. Wikipedia, and the Introselect paper claim that Introselect is *O(n)* in the *worst* case.

Comment: As you stated introselect is a combination of quickselect and median of medians. Quickselect is very fast in average and best case but has a quadratic worst case while median of medians is guaranteed to be a somewhat slower always linear time algorithm. Introselect tries to be fast via quickselect and if it can't be then it falls back to the slower but guaranteed linear time algorithm thus capping its worst case runtime before it becomes worse than linear. Maybe you should clarify your question a bit as it seems there is confusion about what you are asking: STL, Introsort, Complexities?

Comment: @Nobody Rereading my question I can see what you're saying. I'm kinda giving a laundry list of things I don't understand. When all I really wanted to know was how does Introsort work. I hesitate to edit my question now though, because of the efect it would have on previous answers. Hopefully it is enough to just say that your answer solved my problem. If, however, after reading this you still feel the question needs to be edited, I would have no problem with you hacking it up.

Comment: My only concern would be that the current title attracts people looking for another answer than you were. However, Ulrich Eckhardt's answer deals exactly with this question and mine does partially so it would not be a total loss for those coming here because of the title. Anyways, it is a tricky question because there are many possible implementations as you undoubtedly have noticed.

Comment: Read [cppereference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) again carefully. It says nth_element is linear in the *length of the list*, not in n. This question confuses the variables.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I feel like you're making an important point that I don't understand. How would the `distance(first, last)` differ from the size of the input (*n*?)

Comment: Oh just that you should use another letter for the length of the list, because there's already an *n* in *nth* element. I think everyone understood what you meant, but it's good to precise eg. "the nth element of a list length m". The docs say the algorithm is O(m) which is different to O(n)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You asked two questions, the titular one

> How is nth_element Implemented?

Which you already answered:

> There are a lot of claims on StackOverflow and elsewhere that nth_element is O(n) and that it is typically implemented with Introselect.

Which I also can confirm from looking at my stdlib implementation. (More on this later.)

And the one where you don't understand the answer:

> How can an algorithm switch between QSort and Median-of-Medians?

Lets have a look at pseudo code that I extracted from my stdlib:

```
nth_element(first, nth, last)
{ 
  if (first == last || nth == last)
    return;

  introselect(first, nth, last, log2(last - first) * 2);
}

introselect(first, nth, last, depth_limit)
{
  while (last - first > 3)
  {
      if (depth_limit == 0)
      {
          // [NOTE by editor] This should be median-of-medians instead.
          // [NOTE by editor] See Azmisov's comment below
          heap_select(first, nth + 1, last);
          // Place the nth largest element in its final position.
          iter_swap(first, nth);
          return;
      }
      --depth_limit;
      cut = unguarded_partition_pivot(first, last);
      if (cut <= nth)
        first = cut;
      else
        last = cut;
  }
  insertion_sort(first, last);
}
```

Without getting into details about the referenced functions `heap_select` and `unguarded_partition_pivot` we can clearly see, that `nth_element` gives introselect `2 * log2(size)` subdivision steps (twice as much as needed by quickselect in the best case) until `heap_select` kicks in and solves the problem for good.

Comment: Note that the libstdc++ implementation mentioned is not actually introselect, despite the code naming it such. Introselect falls back to a O(n) median-of-medians approach, whereas this implementation falls back to an O(nlogn) heap based solution. (see this bug report for more info: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35968)

Comment: @Azmisov: This touches somewhat on [my old comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145520/how-is-nth-element-implemented/29146718?noredirect=1#comment46544991_29145520). Anyways, thanks for pointing that out. Although it is written plainly in the code, an unsuspecting reader might gloss over the fact that `heap_select` is `O(n log n)`

Answer (score 28):

Disclaimer: I don't know how `std::nth_element` is implemented in any standard library.

If you know how Quicksort works, you can easily modify it to do what is needed for this algorithm.  The basic idea of Quicksort is that in each step, you partition the array into two parts such that all elements less than the pivot are in the left sub-array and all elements equal to or greater than the pivot are in the right sub-array.  (A modification of Quicksort known as ternary Quicksort creates a third sub-array with all elements equal to the pivot.  Then the right sub-array contains only entries strictly greater than the pivot.)  Quicksort then proceeds by recursively sorting the left and right sub-arrays.

If you only want to move the *n*-th element into place, instead of recursing into *both* sub-arrays, you can tell in every step whether you will need to descend into the left or right sub-array.  (You know this because the *n*-th element in a sorted array has index *n* so it becomes a matter of comparing indices.)  So – unless your Quicksort suffers worst-case degeneration – you roughly halve the size of the remaining array in each step.  (You never look at the other sub-array again.)  Therefore, on average, you are dealing with arrays of the following lengths in each step:

1. Θ(*N*)
2. Θ(*N* / 2)
3. Θ(*N* / 4)
4. …

Each step is linear in the length of the array it is dealing with.  (You loop over it once and decide into what sub-array each element should go depending on how it compares to the pivot.)

You can see that after Θ(log(*N*)) steps, we will eventually reach a singleton array and are done.  If you sum up *N* (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + …), you'll get 2 *N*.  Or, in the average case, since we cannot hope that the pivot will always exactly be the median, something on the order of Θ(*N*).

Comment: I assume you know that Quicksort is *O(nlogn)*? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort How would this hope to achieve better than *O(nlogn)* performance?

Comment: @JonathanMee: The sorting needs to sort both sides of the partition while selection only needs to work on the side where the selected element lies. Thus, sorting has to work on all `n` elements `log n` times while, selection only has to deal with the shrinking subsets (as explained in the answer above).

Comment: @Nobody Interesting, I looked into this and this was in fact the pre-Introsort implementation. However both gcc and Visual Studio have gone to Introsort now. Presumably because a bad pivot selection takes Quicksort to a bad place in a hurry.

Comment: @Jonathan: _Presumably because a bad pivot selection takes Quicksort to a bad place in a hurry_ . No. Because the ISO C++ 2011 standard now required std::sort wasn't O(n * log n) on average but it required O(n * log n) for all distributions. This mandated Introsort() to meet this additional requirements. It is a pity that the complexity for std::nth_element  wasn't tightened as well (which would mean QuickSelect is not good enough, IntraSelect would be required).

Answer (score 11):

The code from the [STL](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_algo.h) (version 3.3, I think) is this:

```
template <class _RandomAccessIter, class _Tp>
void __nth_element(_RandomAccessIter __first, _RandomAccessIter __nth,
                   _RandomAccessIter __last, _Tp*) {
  while (__last - __first > 3) {
    _RandomAccessIter __cut =
      __unguarded_partition(__first, __last,
                            _Tp(__median(*__first,
                                         *(__first + (__last - __first)/2),
                                         *(__last - 1))));
    if (__cut <= __nth)
      __first = __cut;
    else 
      __last = __cut;
  }
  __insertion_sort(__first, __last);
}
```

Let's simplify that a bit:

```
template <class Iter, class T>
void nth_element(Iter first, Iter nth, Iter last) {
  while (last - first > 3) {
    Iter cut =
      unguarded_partition(first, last,
                          T(median(*first,
                                   *(first + (last - first)/2),
                                   *(last - 1))));
    if (cut <= nth)
      first = cut;
    else 
      last = cut;
  }
  insertion_sort(first, last);
}
```

What I did here was to remove double underscores and _Uppercase stuff, which is only to protect the code from things the user could legally define as macros. I also removed the last parameter, which is only supposed to help in template type deduction, and renamed the iterator type for brevity.

As you should see now, it partitions the range repeatedly until less than four elements remain in the remaining range, which is then simply sorted.

Now, why is that O(n)? Firstly, the final sorting of up to three elements is O(1), because of the maximum of three elements. Now, what remains is the repeated partitioning. Partitioning in and of itself is O(n). Here though, every step halves the number of elements that need to be touched in the next step, so you have O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4) + O(n/8) which is less than O(2n) if you sum it up. Since O(2n) = O(n), you have linar complexity on average.

Comment: Please note that this seems to be a pure quicksort implementation, there is no algorithm switching going on so it is not introselect.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say, @Nobody.

Comment: You answer the title but not the question `Could someone show me pseudo-code for how Introselect is implemented? Or even better, actual C++ code other than the STL of course :)`. Aside from that I think it is not immediately clear to me that each partition halves the size. I am not sure about `unguarded_partition` but the selected pivot is only the median of the first, middle and last element of the current range which can only guarantee that at least one element is on each side of the pivot, thus requiring linearly many partition steps.

Comment: Regarding the last part I just noticed that you (and the standard) are talking about the average case so this is okay, but it might be good to add that the worst case can (and will) be worse with this algorithm.

Comment: You are right, depending on the data, this could have quadratic runtime, a randomized pivot would be better for that. Concerning the "other than the STL" part, I cheated. However, I wanted to demonstrate how to read such code, because it's a useful skill.

Comment: My main point (from the first comment) was that the OP seemed to be more interested in the algorithm switching in introselect than the actual implementation of `nth_element`. I cheated as well by creating pseudocode from my installed stdlib implementation but I tried to address these questions.