# Is there a way to do nth_element together with copy of data?

Tags: c++, constants, nth-element

I wish to compute the median value from an array of floats in C++:

```
float Median( FloatArray const * constFloatArray )
{
    FloatArray    scratch = FloatArray( *constFloatArray );
    int64_t const size    = scratch.GetWidth() * scratch.GetHeight();
    int64_t const mid     = size / 2;

    std::nth_element( scratch.begin(), scratch.begin() + mid, scratch.end() );

    return scratch[ mid ];
}
```

The FloatArray contains a regular C++ array of floats.

I'm using `std::nth_element` but wonder if there is a facility like `nth_element` that works with `const` data?  Right now, I'm making a copy and then doing `nth_element` before throwing the copy away.  If there isn't something like `nth_element` for `const` data, is there a more efficient approach that uses the copy step to compute information and thus avoid a potentially additional O(n) loop?  Perhaps the performance impact would be negligible?  My array size could be on the order of 2 billion.

Comment: you might want to look into some other algorithm that doesn't modify the source like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930732/c-efficiently-calculating-a-running-median

Comment: You might be able to adjust the `nth_element` algorithm to also copy the elements (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145520/how-is-nth-element-implemented), but I doubt it will be significantly faster. It would be interesting to see the results if you make a performance comparison.

Comment: It’s not possible to select the median without altering the input with o(*n*) extra space, so it’s not a natural candidate for a non-modifying algorithm; nor is there an obvious use for the copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will be more efficient but you can save half of the copying by using [`std::partial_sort_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy).  We can use `std::partial_sort_copy` to copy only half of the data into a new array and it will sort it into that array as it does so.  Then all you need to do is get the last element for an odd number of elements, or average of last two for even amount of elements.  Using a vector that would look like

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 9, 3, 10};
    std::vector<int> r(v.size() / 2 + 1);
    std::partial_sort_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), r.begin(), r.end());
    if (r.size() % 2)
        std::cout << r.back();
    else
        std::cout << (r[r.size() - 1] + r[r.size() - 2]) / 2.0;
}
```

Comment: As I understood it, `nth_element` is surprisingly only O(n), so wouldn't doing a sort would bump it to O(n*log(n))?

Comment: @WilliamKF It will actualy be `O(Nlog(N/2))` but yes it is more algorithmically complex.  It does save half the space though and has half the copies so it could work out to be better, but that is something you need to benchmark on your data set.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The /2 makes no difference inside the O.