# How the worst time complexity of introselect become `O(n)`?

Tags: algorithm, selection-sort

The wikipedia [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) says the worst time complexity is `O(n)`.

However, refer to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146718/7721525, some implementation of introselect runs `2lg(n)` times of `partition_pivot`, which has a worst time complexity of `O(nlg(n))`. Whether you use medians_of_medians algorithm of heapsort, the time complexity is already `O(nlg(n))`.

How to achieve a worst time `O(n)` introselect?
If we use a constant `k` instead of `2lg(n)`. Can we say the time is `O(n)`? Can you give me some practical choices of k( must be a constant)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Specifically, there are some claims that I am not sure where they are arriving from. Mostly: `partition_pivot which has a worst time complexity of nlg(n)`. Moreover, the fact that **an** implementation is suboptimal does not mean the algorithm itself cannot be implemented better.

Comment: @amit thanks, I means `2lg(n)` times of `partition_pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, refer [sic] to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146718/7721525, some implementation of introselect runs `2lg(n)` partition_pivot

As mentioned in the comments there, that implementation is *named* introselect, but it does not actually implement the [introselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect).

> How to achieve a worst time `O(n)` introselect?

You perform quickselect using either a constant number of partitions, or require that the partition is highly imbalanced at most a constant amount of times, and if not done within these restrictions you switch to the [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm.

Note that there's also the recent [QuickSelectAdaptive algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00484) by A. Alexandrescu which goes into detail how to implement deterministic linear-time selection.

Comment: What if `n` is very large? Is the constant `k` unrelated to `n`?
And `k` is closed to `log(n)`, if we still claim it `O(n)` algorithms, how about radix sort?
When talk about radix sort time complexity, it's `O(n*w)` where `w` is length of key.

Comment: @Voyager Read it yourself in the original paper, page 9. *Introspective Sorting and Selection Algorithms* by David R. Musser. Radix sort is something completely different.